# Kubernetes SSL Redirect Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am very new to Kubernetes and I am trying to figure out how to set up a http -> https redirect for my kubernetes cluster. I have searched and have tried many different annotations and I am not sure if I am applying them correctly or not. I have pasted my files below and would be happy to share more if more is necessary.

I have tried to adding these lines to the annotation section

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
```

I have also tried to implement this workaround, but have not had success.

[Redirect workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2724#issuecomment-444835897)

I appreciate the help!

service.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: loadbalancer-ingress
  annotations:
    {{- if .Values.loadbalancer.cert }}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: {{ .Values.loadbalancer.cert | quote }}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "{{- range .Values.loadbalancer.ports -}}{{- if .ssl -}}{{ .name }},{{- end -}}{{- end -}}"
    {{- end }}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: {{ .Values.loadbalancer.backend_protocol | quote }}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector: 
    pod: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  ports:
    {{- range .Values.loadbalancer.ports }}
    - name: {{ .name }}
      port: {{ .port }}
      targetPort: {{ .targetPort }}
    {{- end }}
```

configmap.yaml

```
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-nginx-configuration
data:
  use-proxy-protocol: "false"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  server-tokens: "false"

---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-tcp-services

---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-udp-services
```

values.yaml

```
loadbalancer:
  backend_protocol: http
  cert: MY_AWS_CERT
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      ssl: false
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 80
      ssl: true
```

Comment: where did you add those annotation? can you share the ingress yaml

Comment: I added those annotations to the service.yaml. I do not see an ingress.yaml file. There is a rbac.yaml, deployment.yaml, and Chart.yaml.

Comment: so what doc you are following ? You need to create an ingress resource

Comment: I am unfortunately not following a doc. I have inherited this from the previous worker and I’m trying to update it. Everything seems to be working, but I was hoping I would be able to force users to https

Comment: How would I add an ingress resource? Add an ingress.yaml file and the type would be Ingress? How does that get related to the existing stuff?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have pods and a clusterIP service in front of those pods and then in the ingress resource you can refer to the service. So ingress controller such as nginx will receive the traffic from client which is outside the kubernetes cluster and forward that traffic to the pods behind the service. The ingress controller itself need to be exposed outside the cluster via a LoadBalancer type service.

Referring from docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) an ingress resource will look like

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 3):

## HTTPS for backend

If you wanna to setup `https` as backend traffic, then replace `http`->`https` in `values.yaml`

### Explanation:

`service.yaml` has:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: {{ .Values.loadbalancer.backend_protocol | quote }}
```

It means that `aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol` is declared in `values.yaml`

```
loadbalancer:
  backend_protocol: http
```

According to [`AWS` part of `k8s` man](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#aws):

> `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol`: Used on the service to specify the protocol spoken by the backend (pod) behind a listener. If `http` (default) or `https`, an HTTPS listener that terminates the connection and parses headers is created. If set to `ssl` or `tcp`, a “raw” SSL listener is used. If set to `http` and `aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert` is not used then a HTTP listener is used.

## HTTPS for frontend

If your question about `https` for frontend, then setup an `ingress`-controller.
As per [`ingress` `man` of `k8s`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/):

> You must have an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers) to satisfy an Ingress. **Only creating an Ingress resource has no effect.**
>
> You may need to deploy an Ingress controller such as [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

[AWS](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws) part of  NGINX `ingress` controller installation guide [is here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws):

> In AWS we use a Network load balancer (NLB) to expose the NGINX Ingress controller behind a Service of `Type=LoadBalancer`.
>
> Network Load Balancer (NLB) [¶](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#network-load-balancer-nlb)
>
> ```
> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.32.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml
> ```
>
> `
>
> TLS termination in AWS Load Balancer (ELB) > In some scenarios is required to terminate TLS in the Load Balancer and not in the ingress controller.
>
> For this purpose we provide a template: [deploy-tls-termination.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.32.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy-tls-termination.yaml)
>
> ```
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.32.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy-tls-termination.yaml
> ```
>
> - Edit the file and change:
> - VPC CIDR in use for the Kubernetes cluster: `proxy-real-ip-cidr: XXX.XXX.XXX/XX`
> - AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) ID
>   `arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:XXXXXXXX:certificate/XXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX`
> - Deploy the manifest:
>   `kubectl apply -f deploy-tls-termination.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the follwing annotations to Ingress will do the job:
This will do redirect the followings

1. HTTP => HTTPS
2. non-www => WWW

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |-
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      proxy_ssl_name $host;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: 'true'
```